# Combine audio with ffmpeg breaks video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to combine and audio file (mp3) with a video created with ffmpeg. The video is created from several smaller clips using:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -auto_convert 1 -i videos.txt -c copy -an -sn video.mp4
```

videos.txt contains a list of videos to combine. This video is created correctly and plays fine. Next I am trying to add an audio track to the video. I've checked and the audio file plays correctly however when I add it using the command below the mp4 produced is corrupt and no longer valid for playback:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 audio.aac final.mp4
```

Any ideas, I'm new to using ffmpeg and not sure what half the output means and what is relevant but I don't see anything that looks like errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `-i`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.aac -c copy -shortest final.mp4
```

I added:

- `-c copy` to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) because I assume you only want to mux the audio and not re-encode everything.
- `-shortest` so the output ends when the shortest inputs ends.